# Unnecessary code in windows header

Tags: c++, windows

I started learning windows' header for C++. I understand most of it, except one thing: there is so much unnecessary code. Like, for example, half of the stuff you have to fill out when creating a `WNDCLASSEX` object. I thought about writing a framework for myself to handle this code that I myself will generally not need/use. Is this a common thing or am I missing something?

Comment: Your question is whether it's common for people to write frameworks for themselves?

Comment: Of course it is. I'm asking weather this is common practice for the windows header or is the code that i think of as useless actually useful? Am i overseeing something?

Comment: Or is your question why Microsoft provide such a bad interface? I think that question can be answered by "historically grown" + "backward compatibility", although I'm not an expert on the design and evolution of the Windows API.

Comment: If you want to avoid "unnecessary code" I'd strongly encourage you to look at UI toolkits other than GDI+. Microsoft even offers a number of alternatives -- MFC for example.

Answer (score 0):

The WIN32 API was originally written for C, not C++. It offers a good level of control when writing low level windows application, but indeed it can be cumbersome at some time. For example all the fields in the `WNDCLASSEX` struct have a meaning and control the behaviour of the window it represents. If you want to write a tiny wrapper over the plain Win32 API, please feel free to do it, you will just learn a lot, otherwise there are already some C++ frameworks hiding the cumbersomeness of the lower level Win32 API. Such as MFC (From Microsoft) this is the closest you get to the Windows, or VCL (From Borland, a higher level API for Borland C++ builder) or Qt, a cross platform windowing solution, which is not Windows specific.

But yes, feel free to write your own framework, again, it will be great fun and you'll learn a lot. I did it, I learned a lot.